# Monotouch: Example of an implementation of a finite length task executing when exiting iOS application?

Tags: xamarin.ios

In Apple's docs I have found an article how to execute a finite-length task when exiting the application. I am looking for a way to adopt that in MonoTouch.
The idea is to process some data if the user pushes the app into background, but that processing takes longer than the time I'm granted by default, hence I want to use the functionality describe here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html to get more time.

How does the code translate into MT? Has anybody an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a blog post with an example for MonoTouch: http://software.tavlikos.com/2010/12/08/multitasking-in-ios-the-monotouch-way-part-i/

Comment: Your article states that one can ask fo more time. UIApplication.BackgroundTimeRemaining returns 9.97 seconds for me. How can I "ask" for more time? Or is it implicitly a maximum of 600 seconds when using the BeginBackgroundTask way of doinf it?

Comment: Whenever you call BeginBackgroundTask, you get 600 seconds of background execution time, before your app gets suspended. Basically, it is the BeginBackgroundTask call that asks for "more" time (meaning these 600 seconds). I have also found that if you call BeginBackgroundTask, the time remaining is 600 seconds. If the app moves to the foreground without ending the task and moves to the background again, you get another 600 seconds.